# How to empty HTML table that is filled using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using AJAX to sort table column by the header link,
the problem is whenever I click the link the table not repopulated but instead the rows get repeated, I want to keep the header but empty the table contents,
this is the ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(getData('asc'))
        function getData(sort) {
            $("#tbl > td").empty();

            var srt = sort;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Book/BooksData?sort=' + srt,
                dataTtype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                        $('#tbl').append('<tr><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td>' + val.Author.Name + '</td></tr>')
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

the HTML:

```
<table id="tbl" class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getData('@ViewBag.Sort')" id="sort">Title</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            Author
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in the jQuery code I also tried `tbl` and `tbl>tr` and `remove` function 
but none works!

**UPDATE:**

As Zakaria Acharki suggests in his answer, I made these changes:

HTML:

```
<table id="tbl" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getData('@ViewBag.Sort')" id="sort">Title</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                Author
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(getData('asc'))
    function getData(sort) {
        var srt = sort;
        $('#tbl>tbody').html('<tr><td>Title</td><td>Author Name</td></tr>'); // why did you add this?

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Book/BooksData?sort=' + srt,
            dataTtype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, val) {
                    $('#tbl>tbody').html('<tr><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td>' + val.Author.Name + '</td></tr>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

but when the page loads there is only one row rendered, also there is a line below  the header:
[image]

Comment: `#tbl>tr` works

Comment: @RápliAndrás That'll also clear the header row too.

Comment: You can use $('#tbl td').parent().remove();

Comment: I just pointed out that he was missing the `#`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `thead/tbody` then use `.empty()` to remove the current data and `.append()` to add the new data from the ajax request.

**HTML :**

```
<table id="tbl" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
            <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getData('@ViewBag.Sort')" id="sort">Title</a>
        </th>
        <th>
            Author
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#tbl>tbody').empty();

$.each(data, function (index, val) {
    $('#tbl>tbody').append('<tr><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td>' + val.Author.Name + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(getData('asc'))
function getData(sort) {
  $('#tbl>tbody').empty();
  
  var data = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'};
  
  $.each(data, function (index, val) {
    $('#tbl>tbody').append('<tr><td>Title</td><td>Author Name</td></tr>');
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="getData('@ViewBag.Sort')" id="sort">Title</a>
      </th>
      <th>
        Author
      </th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I whole heartedly support this method. The use of the extra semantic elements makes the problem easy to solve (i.e. `$('#tbl > tbody').empty();`)...

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki There's a problem, the header has disappeared and there is only one row rendered!

Comment: @War10ck the header has disappeared also :(

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Then the markup is not rendered correctly. The headers should only be present in the `<thead></thead>` element. Please post the relevant (updated) markup in your question.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed that may caused by the line `$("#tbl > td").empty();` please remove it..

Comment: @MohamedAhmed i've added the part `$('#tbl>tbody').html('<tr><td>Title</td><td>Author Name</td></tr>');` just for the test purpose (No need to add it in your code), for you the `$('#tbl>tbody').html('<tr><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td>' + val.Author.Name + '</td></tr>');
` is enough

Comment: It works better now, but why this happens: http://i.imgur.com/kUNp3UZ.gif ?

Comment: Try to fix the width of th columns, that happen when the `empty()` remove all the tbody rows then the table will be adjusted automatically, you will see that clear if you comment the line `$('#tbl>tbody').append...`.